# Does GDB shows wrong data when run over an compiler optimized binary image?

Tags: c, debugging, assembly, gdb, callstack

I am having a code like -

```
100 static void
101 func (<struct type1> *arg1, <struct type2> **arg2)
102 {
103   <struct type2> *var1;
...
...
...
112    var1 = *arg2; /* arg2 is no where else used in this function */
113    if (!var1) {
114        return;
115    }
...
...   /* var1 has been referenced to read its properties and to set its properties */
120
...
...
125    my_free();       /* crash happened at this line - my_free() would call __free() */
...
...
130
     }
```

The program has crashed and created a core like -

```
#2  0x000055ea29cceb76 in func [__be_func...] (arg1=arg1@entry=0x7f8bcc440098, arg2=arg2@entry=0x0) at myfile.c:121
```

You could notice that the second argument `arg2` is shown by GDB as 0x0.
However, if it was NULL then program could have crashed at line#112 itself.

So I decided to disassemble the code and below is the excerpt after disassembling the above function -

```
(gdb) disass
Dump of assembler code for function func:
   0x000055ea29cce790 <+0>:     push   %rbp
   0x000055ea29cce791 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
   0x000055ea29cce794 <+4>:     push   %r15
   0x000055ea29cce796 <+6>:     push   %r14
   0x000055ea29cce798 <+8>:     push   %r13
   0x000055ea29cce79a <+10>:    push   %r12
   0x000055ea29cce79c <+12>:    push   %rbx
   0x000055ea29cce79d <+13>:    sub    $0x38,%rsp
   0x000055ea29cce7a1 <+17>:    mov    %rdi,%r14
   0x000055ea29cce7a4 <+20>:    movabs $0x8000000000000000,%r15
   0x000055ea29cce7ae <+30>:    addq   $0x1,0x1864a08a(%rip) 
   0x000055ea29cce7b6 <+38>:    lea    -0x1(%r15),%rdx
   0x000055ea29cce7ba <+42>:    mov    %rdi,-0x38(%rbp)
   0x000055ea29cce7be <+46>:    and    %rdx,%r14
   0x000055ea29cce7c1 <+49>:    and    %rdx,%rsi
   0x000055ea29cce7c4 <+52>:    mov    $0xffffffffffffff7f,%r13
   0x000055ea29cce7cb <+59>:    and    0x50(%r14),%r13
   0x000055ea29cce7cf <+63>:    movl   $0x1000000,-0x50(%rbp)
   0x000055ea29cce7d6 <+70>:    movl   $0x0,-0x48(%rbp)
   0x000055ea29cce7dd <+77>:    mov    (%rsi),%rcx
   0x000055ea29cce7e0 <+80>:    bswap  %rcx
   0x000055ea29cce7e3 <+83>:    mov    %rcx,%rbx
   0x000055ea29cce7e6 <+86>:    mov    %rdx,-0x40(%rbp)
   0x000055ea29cce7ea <+90>:    and    %rdx,%rbx
   0x000055ea29cce7ed <+93>:    je     0x55ea29ccebcb
   0x000055ea29cce7f3 <+99>:    bswap  %r13
   0x000055ea29cce7f6 <+102>:   testb  $0x20,0x10d0(%r14)
   0x000055ea29cce7fe <+110>:   jne    0x55ea29cce80b
   0x000055ea29cce800 <+112>:   cmpl   $0x0,0x48(%r14)
   0x000055ea29cce805 <+117>:   je     0x55ea29cce9e1
   0x000055ea29cce80b <+123>:   mov    %rsi,-0x58(%rbp)
   0x000055ea29cce80f <+127>:   mov    0x1210(%r14),%r11
   0x000055ea29cce816 <+134>:   bswap  %r11
   ...
   ...
   ...
   ...
```

My analysis is -
Since `arg2` is only used at line# 112, may be due to compiler optimisation, it is not saved onto the stack frame and just held in register `%rsi`. And once after the execution of line# 112, the value in `%rsi` has got changed and `arg2` is lost indefinitely.
If my analysis is correct, shouldn't GDB shown `arg2` as `<optimized out>` in the callstack rather than as 0x0?

---

Edit#1 to my analysis -
when I dumped the stackframe of the function `func`

```
(gdb) i r rbp
rbp            0x7f8bcd651730      0x7f8bcd651730
(gdb) x/13xg 0x7F8BCD6516D0
0x7f8bcd6516d0: 0x0000000b00000006      
                0x00007f8bcd651748   <--- stored register %rsi value, which represents the 2nd argument - ie `arg2`
0x7f8bcd6516e0: 0x0000000001000000
                0x0000000000000000
0x7f8bcd6516f0: 0x7fffffffffffffff      
                0x80007f8bcc440098   <--- stored register %rdi value, which represents the 1st argument - ie `arg1` 
0x7f8bcd651700: 0x80007f8bd51a6230      
                0x00007f8bd51a6248
0x7f8bcd651710: 0x00007f8bcd651748      
                0x00007f8bd51a6230
0x7f8bcd651720: 0x80007f8bcc440098      
                0x0000000000000000
0x7f8bcd651730: 0x00007f8bcd651780
```

As you can see the 2nd argument `arg2` is not really NULL.

Important thing to notice is - 1st argument is stored as `0x80007f8bcc440098`, whereas 2nd argument is stored as `0x00007f8bcd651748`.
The difference is that 1st argument's MSB bit is set to 1.
Why is GDB not printing rightly when the address's MSB is not set to 1?

Comment: Something like that might be possible.  You're right that `0x000055ea29cce7dd   mov    (%rsi),%rcx` would have crashed if `arg2` had been NULL on function entry.  But was the crash in an inlined copy of `func`?  The crash address at `...b76` is 908 bytes after the `...7ea and %rdx,%rbx` at the end of your disassembly.  Unless the code between those lines compiled to a huge auto-vectorized loop, or some functions inlined, that might be in another function.

Comment: I have slightly added more information inside the function `func` to provide clarity on where it has crashed. Inside `func`, we are calling `my_free` which would inturn call `free`. And the crash has happened inside the `__free` function call. If you observe the callstack that I have shared it is frame#2.

What do you mean by "But was the crash in an inlined copy of `func`?"

Comment: Optimization can inline functions at their call-sites.  But debug info can keep track of which function a block of machine code came from, even if the preceding asm symbol is actually a parent function.  But it wouldn't show up in the backtrace that way, so probably not that.

Comment: One more question - If the assembly code `...e7dd <+77>:    mov    (%rsi),%rcx` represents the C code `var1 = *arg2;` then what is the impact of the statement `...7c1 <+49>:    and    %rdx,%rsi` - ain't we modifying the value of %rsi even before using it later?

Comment: Yes, IDK why your compiler is clearing the high bit of pointers before deref, or why it's generating the RDX value as `0x8000000000000000 - 1` with an LEA instead of `movabs $0x7fffffffffffffff`; maybe it uses the R15 constant later?  Anyway, x86-64 addresses have to be correctly sign-extended from 48-bit (or 57), so clearing just the high bit makes it fault if it had previously been a high-half (kernel) address.

Comment: I was wondering before what compiler would be using a `%rbp` frame pointer with optimization enabled, but now that you point that out, I'm much more curious about this asm.  Also about clunky optimization choices like `mov    $0xffffffffffffff7f,%r13` / `and  0x50(%r14),%r13` instead of `mov 0x50(%r14),%r13` / `and $0xffffffffffffff7f,%r13` which would be the same number of uops for the front-end (with micro-fusion), but smaller machine-code size (imm8 instead of imm32), and fewer uops for the back-end.

Comment: Well, I see few line down the disassembled code, the asm `0x000055ea29cce80b <+123>:   mov    %rsi,-0x58(%rbp)` which essentially indicates that `%rsi` (`arg2`) is stored on stack frame, right?

Comment: Yes, if the `cmpl $0x0,0x48(%r14)` / `je` right before it isn't taken.   That's checking something in `arg1->...`.  Perhaps debug info is indicating to look there, but it was never actually reached due to the jump being taken?  Ideally you can re-run the program and modify inputs with a debugger to produce this crash, so you *know* how you got there and what the right values actually were.  Then you can know whether debug info can be wrong for this.

Comment: I did some of analysis to understand the statements -
from `0x000055ea29cce7ed <+93>:    je     0x55ea29ccebcb` 
to `0x000055ea29cce805 <+117>:   je     0x55ea29cce9e1`.


They are representing the C code which are some basic checking `if (arg1 == NULL) return;` or `if (arg1.property1 == NULL) return;`.
So only in those error cases, we are not going to store the `arg2` in stack

Comment: @PeterCordes By the way, I am not able to reproduce the crash once again.

Comment: When I dumped the stack frame, I observed that `%rsi` data processes (ie ANDing the `%rsi` with `0x7fffffffffffffff`) and stored as `0x00007f8bcd651748` in stack frame.
However, the `%rdi` data is unprocessed and stored as `0x80007f8bcc440098` in the stack frame. Could it be that the GDB be able to read and properly understand if the value is unprocessed? Hence it is able to display `%rdi` properly and not `%rsi`.

Comment: IDK if tagged pointers could be crossing up GDB's efforts to follow variables.  It's reporting `arg2=arg2@entry=0x0`, not trying to dereference anything.  (And that explains why it's ANDing; these aren't correctly-sign-extended pointers, so clearly they're using the high bit for something.  Using the low bit would be cheaper to clear and about as cheap to test, BTW, assuming the pointers have some required alignment so the low bit is available.  Using the high bit has a nice noisy failure mode if you forget to clear it, though.  Hmm, I wonder if this is `-fsanitize=something`)

Comment: Also, you should be able to make it crash by using `set $rsi = whatever` or `set *(int*)$rsi = whatever` or similar at an appropriate time.  That's what I was suggesting earlier, so you *know* how you crashed it, and what register values actually were, and can compare that with what GDB reports.  (Of course, the debug info might be assuming that registers and memory don't change when the asm wouldn't have changed them.)

Comment: @PeterCordes Sorry, I couldn't understand your last but one comment. Could you please make that explanation more simpler?

Comment: The program might have been compiled with `-fsanitize=address` or something.  That might be why it's using the high bit of the address for something when the C source isn't casting to `uintptr_t` and masking before dereferences.  I don't know if that explains anything, other than the fact that you observed a `0x80007f8bcc440098` address (which GDB can't deref, but probably could if you did `x (0x80007f8bcc440098 & 0xffffffffffff)` to clear the high 16 bits, since user-space addresses are in the low 47 bits.)  Using extra bits of a pointer for other data is called a "tagged pointer".

Comment: Thanks for making it simple @PeterCordes
Regarding GDB understanding tagged pointer.
When I want to read a memory at a certain location then I will have to remove the MSB bit by ANDing address with `7fffffffffffffff`. ie `0x80007f8bcc440098` AND `7fffffffffffffff` would give `0x00007f8bcc440098` and I can access this address.
However, GDB in the call stack has printed the value of `arg1` which is stored as tagged pointer on stack frame - `0x80007f8bcc440098`. However, GDB has not been able to rightly decode the `arg2` which is stored on stack frame as `0x00007f8bcd651748`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appear to be an issue with compiler.
Output of `info address arg2` showed that 2nd argument `arg2` doesn't contains an entry in stack location.